# Efficiently dealing with multiple HTML elements with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I have a 4 `div` tags in my view:

```
<div class="tile"></div>
<div class="tile"></div>
<div class="tile"></div>
<div class="tile"></div>
```

And let's say that when the user selects clicks on one of them I want the rest to, say, turn red. Normally in a dirty jQuery style I'd use something like:

```
var tiles = $('.tile');

tiles.click(function()
{
  tiles.css('background', 'red');
});
```

However, how would I do this in the world of AngularJS? Would I stick this code in the controller and have it relative to the `$scope`? Or would I create a `directive` and bind that to each tile element?

Comment: Are these div tags static or created using ng-repeat?

Comment: Why would that matter? They'll have the same class so they can be static or dynamically created; they'll all be in the same parent tag though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you wouldn't just have 4 random tiles in your interface not bound to some kind of model, you could do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/V4YC9/1/

HTML

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="x">
    <div ng-repeat="tile in tiles" ng-click="selectTile(tile)" ng-class="tile.class">{{tile.name}}</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function x($scope) {
    $scope.selectedTileIndex = null;

    $scope.tiles = [
        {id: 1, name: 'tile 1'},
        {id: 2, name: 'tile 2'},
        {id: 3, name: 'tile 3'},
        {id: 4, name: 'tile 4'}
    ];

    // provide default class to all tiles
    angular.forEach($scope.tiles, function (tile) {
        tile.class = 'tile';
    });

    $scope.selectTile = function (clickedTile) {
        angular.forEach($scope.tiles, function (tile) {
            tile.class = 'tileNotSelected';
        });

        clickedTile.class = 'tileSelected';
    }
}
```

Edit: There are probably 10 different ways to do it.  If you don't want to muddy up your model, you could store a separate array in $scope and calculate the class real time by saying `ng-class="calculateTileClass(tile)"`, similar to what I did in my initial response: http://jsfiddle.net/V4YC9/1/

Comment: Ah so here you've put the logic in the `$scope` controller vs a directive; why? What if I wanted the same logic applied to the same pattern of boxes but within a different part of the application? Wouldn't a directive make _more_ sense?

Comment: Certainly, if you intend to reuse a set of elements or some paradigm, putting it in a directive is the way to go.  I was just illustrating the "Angular Way" of accomplishing the task.  It should translate fairly easily to a directive assuming you have some structure (an array) to wrap it around.

Comment: So the issue here is that the controller is bound to the parent `$scope` and the tiles exist within that; however as a `directive` would I have to apply the scope to the parent element rather than the child tiles?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking, here's the same code as a directive: http://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/V4YC9/2/.  The parent scope is still modified (to add a class property), but you could hide that away in a different variable so as not to modify the model.  Again, the right answer to this question all really depends on knowing all of your requirements and how your UI will flow.  I'm just illustrating a rudimentary example of how you can achieve this in Angular.